# How do I make Excel extract percentages from a cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, extract, percentage

Has anyone figured out how to extract the numbers 4.25%-4.5% and 4%-4.5% from the cell?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

I tried the formula for the value on the left:

`=IFERROR(IF(D5="",0,LEFT(D5,FIND("%",D5))+0),"N/A")`

I tried the formula for the value on the right:

`=IFERROR(IF(D5="",0,RIGHT(D5,FIND("%",D5))+0),"N/A")`

It works for Baltimore but is not working for New Jersey for me.

Comment: Can you please confirm what result you want.
Like Baltimore 4.25-4.5
Northern New Jersey 4-4.5 If you want result as i asked above then please use below formula:-
=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"%","")

Comment: Fyi, while your formulas seem clunky to me (no offense) they do work on my version of Excel for `4%-4.5%` (as you typed). Looking at your screen shot, you might have some spaces in there causing some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should work. You're probably missing converting string to a number.

```
=LEFT(D6,FIND("-",D6)-1)+0
=MID(D6,FIND("-",D6)+1,LEN(D6))+0
```

You could use the `value` function, but I just use `+0` as it's easy to remember as it's shorter and how I most frequently RSVP to social invitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(D5,"-")
```

If you need to do error checking, and return the percentages as numeric value instead of a text string, then:

```
=--IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(D5,"-"),NA())
```

and format the cells as `%` or General or Number with desired number of decimals.